# Linq DateTime Operations Comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have this statement

```
SearchResults = (from s in dbContext.tbl_ShippingProgram
                 where s.eta_date.Date > DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-TimePeriod.Value)
                 select s).ToList();
```

Where SearchResults is defined as

```
public List<tbl_ShippingProgram> SearchResults { get; set; }
```

And where TimePeriod.Value is a int

I'm having difficulties figuring out why this doesn't work, there's nothing wrong the with just selecting all values since

```
SearchResults = (from s in dbContext.tbl_ShippingProgram
                 select s).ToList();
```

Works perfectly fine. Any and all help is appreciated <3

EDIT
 - The issue is that it's not returning anything where it definately should be, checked the values in the db and the calculated DateTime.Now value and it should be returning something
[image: Some Example rows that should be returning, the eta date is the first date field]

Comment: What is not working? Is this throwing an exception?

Comment: Nah it's just not returning any values, but it should be. I checked the calculated values of the DateTime.Now and it definately is less than some values in my DB

Comment: `I have a hunch that it's something to do with the format of the date time...` Nah.  Dates dont have a format - they are just a value *expressed in a format* mere humans can understand

Comment: Can you show us an example row that's *actually* in the database, that you believe should be returned?

Comment: I added a screencap of some, the first date field is the eta, the datetime.today.addmonths(-TimeRange.Value) is used to set the comparable date.

Comment: @Impulse And what is `TimeRange.Value` set to?

Comment: It can be anything, I was just using 24 since that would end up being 24 months

Comment: Can you please create a `var data = new List<tbl_ShippingProgram>() { new tbl_ShippingProgram() { Xxx = xxx, Yyyy = yyy } }` etc of sample data and then show your query against this data? You need to replicate your database issue in code that _we can run_.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-TimePeriod.Value).Date`

I think you want the date portion of the datetime after the adjustment.  This trips me up all the time too...

Couple of other things to try if this doesn't help:

1. Calculate the date outside of your linq statement (although you're not getting an unsupported error, but still).
2. Try using .Compare() for datetimes.
3. Do some sanity checking by using a hard-coded date that clearly encompass all results.